# How to mirror selection without adding new polygons/vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices, mirror

Let's say I want to select some vertices on the left arm of a model, I want it to also select the same vertices on the right side, the model already has both sides but without the mirror modifier

I don't want to make any new polygons/vertices

Comment: If the object is completely symmetrical and its origin is centred, you can select your vertices on one side, hit Ctrl-Shift-M to select the mirror and check the Extend entry on the bottom-left Operator panel which appears.

Comment: That kind of works but if I try to move one vertex closer to the center the other one goes further, and I'd like to have it automated, is my best bet to try and cut the model in half and add a mirror modifier?

Comment: Yes! If you have a centre edge which runs right round the model vertically, select it with the Alt key in Edge mode, hit 'V' to rip it, hover over one side of the model and hit Ctrl-L to select that side, X > Vertices to delete it then add your mirror modifier.

Comment: I can't loop select it, what now? I don't want to do actual work

Comment: Can you add an image or share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Am I allowed to share it if it's nude and depicts a child

Comment: Definitely not! :^(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what I was looking for.

To use it, select an object and go into Edit Mode and you should see a butterfly icon with X,Y,Z being near it in the top right corner of the scene.

[image]